# Jquery not being called on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im fairly new to `JQuery` so forgive me if this is simple.

I have this function:

```
$(function(){
   $("#usermenu-drop").width($("#usermenu").width() + 3);
   $("#usermenu").click(function(){$("#usermenu-drop").toggle();});
});
```

The `click` works just fine, but the dynamic width setting `$("#usermenu-drop").width($("#usermenu").width() + 3);` is never happening. Why is this? I have run that line in console and it works.

Comment: Did you put it inside document.ready()   http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @JohnWilliams That's what `$(function)` does.

Comment: @JohnWilliams Do you not see the `$()` ?

Comment: is that width you're adding to available when you try to re-set it? is that element dynamically rendered to to start with?

Comment: when you say "i have run that line in the console and it works", and yet its not working ... define works.

Comment: If the click works, jQuery is obviously loaded, but the element doesn't return the right width, or you're setting the width on the wrong element, and 3 pixels isn't much

Comment: @PlantTheIdea it changes the width.

Comment: it changes the width ... but your saying the dynamic width setting is never happening. its a confusing dichotomy, perhaps you could elaborate.

Comment: @adeneo its the width of `usermenu` + 3 pixels.

Comment: It seems like the most likely issue is that either `#usermenu-drop` isn't yet created or `#usermenu` isn't yet visible and thus doesn't yet have it's width.  Some simple `console.log()` statements will tell you if either of these is the case.

Comment: why are you doing two widths on the same selector? it is going to ignore the first one and do the second, you want the value of the width () which is what an empty does, do it on the next line. Else the parse says two widths *do* the last one.  Break that into two lines.

Comment: also look at (https://api.jquery.com/width/#width-value) for the proper use. "An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer along with an optional unit of measure appended (as a string)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(function)` is called only when the DOM hierarchy is finished loading, but not necessarily the things inside the DOM (such as images).

You should attatch that function to a `load` handler, such as:

```
$(function(){
   $("#usermenu").click(function(){$("#usermenu-drop").toggle();});
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
   $("#usermenu-drop").width($("#usermenu").width() + 3);
});
```

Comment: There is no load event for an item in your static HTML.

Comment: @jfriend00 Whoops, fixed.

Comment: I used `$(window).on("load", function() {` without enclosing it in the DOM load function and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what your html is like, but usually for a dropdown menu with a toggle button I wrap the drop down and toggle button with a div and style both using CSS, that way you won't need to do any javascript regarding layout.

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kPTW/

HTML

```
<div id="usermenu-wrap">
    <a href="#" id="usermenu-button">Toggle</a>
    <div id="usermenu-dropdown">
        stuff in here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#usermenu-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

#usermenu-button {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
}

#usermenu-dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 198px;
    border: 1px solid #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#usermenu-button').click( function() {
        $('#usermenu-dropdown').toggle();
    });
});
```